# Resolution failure for plugin when added to libraryDependencies in project?

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

When I run `sbt publishLocal`, the plugin will be generated in `<ivy-repository>/<org>/<plugin>/<scala-version>/<sbt-version>/<plugin-version>/...`

For example:

```
[info]  published sbt-cloudengine to /Users/hanxue/.ivy2/local/net.entrypass/sbt-cloudengine/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2.1/jars/sbt-cloudengine.jar
```

How can I exclude `<scala-version>` and `<sbt-version>` from the output path?

This path is causing resolution failure when I add the plugin as a dependency in `build.sbt`:

```
[warn] ==== Local Ivy Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///Users/hanxue/.ivy2/local/net/entrypass/sbt-cloudengine/0.2.1/sbt-cloudengine-0.2.1.pom
```

Plugin's `build.sbt` is:

```
sbtPlugin := true

name := "sbt-cloudengine"

organization := "net.entrypass"

version := "0.2.1"

description := "sbt plugin for managing Google Cloud Engine resources"

licenses := Seq("BSD License" -> url("https://github.com/hanxue/sbt-cloudengine/blob/master/LICENSE"))

scalacOptions := Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked")

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := true

publishArtifact in (Test, packageBin) := false

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false

publishMavenStyle := false
```

---

### Update 1

This is how the plugin is referenced in a project's `<rootdir>/build.sbt`

```
resolvers += "Local Ivy Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.ivy2/local"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "net.entrypass" % "sbt-cloudengine" % "0.2.1"
)
```

This is the directory listing

```
$ ls -R ~/.ivy2/local/net.entrypass/sbt-cloudengine/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2.1/
ivys    jars    poms

/Users/hanxue/.ivy2/local/net.entrypass/sbt-cloudengine/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2.1//ivys:
ivy.xml     ivy.xml.md5 ivy.xml.sha1

/Users/hanxue/.ivy2/local/net.entrypass/sbt-cloudengine/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2.1//jars:
sbt-cloudengine.jar     sbt-cloudengine.jar.sha1
sbt-cloudengine.jar.md5

/Users/hanxue/.ivy2/local/net.entrypass/sbt-cloudengine/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2.1//poms:
sbt-cloudengine.pom     sbt-cloudengine.pom.sha1
sbt-cloudengine.pom.md5
```

Comment: Can you show us how you reference your plugin as a dependency?

Comment: Does it work with "net.entrypass" %% "sbt-cloudengine" % "0.2.1" (note the two `%`) ?

Comment: @LomigMégard no, does not work. I believe that will only include the scala version. Dependency still fail for `[info]   +-net.entrypass:sbt-cloudengine_2.10:0.2.1 (error: not found)`

Comment: hmmm perhaps it's because you're referencing a plugin as a library... Try adding it in the `project/plugins.sbt` file with `addSbtPlugin("net.entrypass" % "sbt-cloudengine" % "0.2.1")`.

Comment: @LomigMégard Indeed! Thanks so much for pointing it out I mixed up a plugin with library dependency. If you are kind enough to write an answer, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're publishing a sbt plugin and not a library, the path will correctly contain the sbt version and the scala version. 
Your problem comes from the fact you're trying to load the plugin using the `libraryDependencies`. Instead, you have to use the file `project/plugins.sbt` with the following inside:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.entrypass" % "sbt-cloudengine" % "0.2.1")
```

This way, sbt will search the plugin using the correct path with the help of the current scala and sbt versions.